# Make object of 'A' type as instance of 'B' type in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I am asking may look weird, but here is an example:

I have a **class 'A'**

```
class A:
    a=1
```

other I have **class 'B'**

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj # obj is any object
```

Now I use:

```
first = A()
second = B(first)
isinstance(second, A)
```

I want **step 3 to be true**. i.e. whatever object class B is taking, it should **add instance** of that **object type** to object.

Is something like this possible in Python?

Comment: But `B` _isn't_ an `A`! Do you want Python to lie?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by the way? Why does step 3 need to be true?

Comment: I'll add my voice to the rising chorus: this sounds like a terrible idea.  You're going against the grain of the language, and I am certain there's a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: Here I want to make a python object which supports concept of public and private variables.
You make any class and make a new object
b=Freeze(a,['item'])
it means make a object b, which do everytihng as object a and 'item' is private variable there.
You can see the code at github:
https://github.com/paritosh90/Python-Freeze/blob/master/freeze/freeze.py

Comment: I would just prepend the names of the variables with a single or double underscore to indicate they are private. If someone wants to muck around with them: let them. If code breaks because they did then it is their problem; they decided to change private variables.

Comment: That would be my practical suggestion. Despite that, I would really like to see if this can be done.

Comment: I'm failing to see what this achieves over a `collections.namedtuple` between "consenting adults" ?

Comment: Exactly your idea is really genuine and practical, but if we give user power to declare any variable as private, it would be good for him, i think..

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Thing is though, whatever sandbox you set up, with enough determination someone would be able to gain access to the private variables. It might be possible to completely prevent this if you use the Python C API, but I really doubt it would be possible in pure Python.

Comment: Haven't looked at your code on github yet, but basically there is no 'private' variables in Python. The `__` prefix just mangles the name with the current module or class name, that is `__bar` inside class `Foo` will just be mangled to `_Foo_bar`. It appears private because the when the interpreter encounters `__` it inserts the current module/class name which unless its the same class it was declared in it won't match. See http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#i-try-to-use-spam-and-i-get-an-error-about-someclassname-spam

Comment: Python has a convention for things that shouldn't be mucked around with, and that is `__something` (or for things that could be for derived classes is `_something`) - the language doesn't include `public`, `protected`, `private` or `friend` mechanisms. You can't make private an attribute of a Python class in a C++ style.

Comment: Yes, i know there is no private variable in python, I am trying to make a class which makes it act like that.. :)

Comment: @JPvdMerwe, Yes your point is correct, one can easily access these variables. I am trying to find some solution for this, this is the big hurdle.

Comment: But Paritosh - there is no point. If someone wants to get to the variable, they can completely bypass any machinery you put in place, and there's a naming convention that's established which all Python developers understand as to what might be okay to alter, or should be well left alone (unless you're savvy with what you're doing)

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier that someone can easily get access to variable if he/she knows python well, but then it is a try, may be we come out with some mechanism which makes it act as we want, more over if not public or private, we can make it act as freeze only.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: you are barking up the wrong tree.  Why try to make Python act like another language?  You're putting a lot of work into fighting the language.  Write documentation that tells your users not to touch the private stuff, and be done with it.  Also, I don't even understand how this achieves the effect of private variables?

Comment: @JonClements: Double underscore names are not great for merely indicating that they are private. I would *strongly* prefer single underscore names for that. Double underscore names are intended for when you need a name that won't be shared with other unknown users of the same namespace (tends to come up in abstract base classes, or decorators/metaclasses that add secret attributes to other objects they otherwise don't control). Nearly every time I have used a double underscore name where I didn't actually need this functionality I have regretted it later, because the mangling is a PITA.

Comment: @NedBatchelder as i told earlier that may be we can't achieve the private effect, but atleast we can have frozen effect, i.e. if we want some variable not to be accessed outside class, we can freeze it. In case, if someone intentionally wants he can access it through some mechanism, but by chance it should not be accessible.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course override the `__new__` and derive your object from `type` instead of `object` effectively creating a class factory...

What you end up doing is very similar to:

```
b = type('B', (A,), {'obj': A()})
```

Which generates a `class B` derived from A, containing that instance of A() - since this is a function you can pass whatever you fancy in for whatever reason you wish to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Using inheritance, yes:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj # obj is any object
```

Comment: But it needs to work for arbitrary `A`: would `B` need to inherit from countless base classes?

Comment: Yes i know using inheritance this can be done, but what i asked is i want to pass any object, it not specifically object of class A, it can be object of class C, D, E; any class.. :)

Comment: The I'd ask what katrielalex asks. Please tell us what you want to accomplish, maybe there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

2 Possibilities

instead of `isinstance(second, A)` do `isinstance(second.obj, A)`

Second... more hackish way is to do something like this:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj # obj is any object
        self.__class__ = obj.__class__
```

This is hackish as it basically fools the interpreter into into thinking the instance is a different class. That is `isinstance(second, B)` will return `False`

To answer the question posed below: the interpreter will basically act as if `second` is a class `A` and nothing defined at the class level in `B` will remain. eg if you do something like

```
class B:
    b=2 #Won't be visible
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj # obj is any object
        self.b2 = 5 #Instance variable will be visible
        self.__class__ = obj.__class__

    def someFunc(self): #Won't be visible
        return 3
```

Using the same code as you used above for initialization here is what will happen with some calls using the interpreter. In general any class variables or methods will be removed and instead use `A`'a, however any instance variables will be remembered. Because of this doing `self.obj = obj` is a bit redundant. Basically instantiating `B(obj)`  will more or less return an object of the same class as `obj`. Though it won't call `obj`'s `__init__`, for that you will need some more voodoo/magic (if you're interested just post).

```
>>> isinstance(second, A)
True
>>> isinstance(second, B)
False
>>> second.a
1
>>> second.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    second.b
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'b'
>>> second.someFunc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    second.someFunc()
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'someFunc'
>>> second.b2
5
>>> second.obj
<__main__.A instance at 0x0123CAF8>
```

Comment: can you please tell me any major use case which may create problem....., i think this is right :)

Comment: I wouldn't have believed it is as simple as just changing `__class__`. One thing you could try is setting up a `__getattr__()` that defers look up to `B`.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe You couldn't declare it inside of `B` directly, but I suppose you could do something like `self.__getattr__ = B.__getattr__`, though I'm not 100% sure that will work (set instance function to a class function), plus if the original class defined `__getattr__()` you would need to add logic to defer to that when needed...

Comment: Normal methods will be looked up first in the instance then the class (just as any other attribute), so overriding them with instance attributes will work. There's a handful of special methods that jump straight to the class though, and I believe `__getattr__` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to suggest that this is highly unlikely to be a good idea even if it's possible in a non-hackish way. (Edit: Jon Clements' suggestion strikes me as the best/least hackish way but I still suggest the rest of my post is relevant.)   I'd further hazard to suggest this is conflating/confusing an "is-a" relationship with what should probably be a "has-a" relationship.  Impossible to know for sure unless more details are posted about what the OP is trying to achieve.

Anyway, someone (Kent Beck I think) once said (paraphrasing as I remember it) that inheritance creates very powerful coupling between bodies of code with attendant difficulties in maintenance and enhancement and that therefore inheritance should really be pretty deep down in your bag of tricks and shouldn't be used lightly.  Put differently: Prefer composition (or aggregation) over inheritance where at all possible.

Comment: I agree - hierarchy and containment is more useful statically. I just posted my answer to show it is possible to "muck about with" construction of any Python class.